# Limiting download speed based on other LAN traffic

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bandwidth, traffic

I'm kind of new to Linux (but learning) so bare with me if I say something stupid :P.

I'm currently running an Ubuntu fileserver which automates a whole bunch of downloading tasks. At present it is set to throttle downloads at certain times so I don't impact too much on casual browsing iPlayer etc during peak times. But this is not ideal.

I was wondering if it is possible to limit overall system bandwidth usage based on sniffing packets from other systems on the LAN that are going to/from specific URLS (e.g. iplayer)

If somebody could point me in the direction of the relevant tools, I'm happy to do the research myself. Just right now I wouldn't know where to start...

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches that come to mind.

#### Method #1 - iptables

Yes it is possible through `iptables` to throttle traffic based on either the TCP port(s) it's making use of or the source IP addresses that it's originating from. I would need to know specifics in order to assist in crafting actual rules for your situation.

#### Method #2 - traffic shaping QoS

The other approach is to throttle specific applications using tools such as [Wondershaper](http://lartc.org/wondershaper/) or [Trickle](http://monkey.org/~marius/pages/?page=trickle).

#### Examples

To throttle the upload/download speed to 20Kbps.

```
$ trickle -d 20 wget -c http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-stable.noarch.rpm
```

You can also set these independently in the above scenario. You can also make these settings the default like so.

```
$ trickled -d 50 -u 10
```

You can also use Wondershaper to control the bandwidth at the network level. For example say I want to throttle my `eth1` device.

```
$ sudo wondershaper eth1 1024 256
```

This will give me a Download speed of 1024 Kbits and 256 Kbits Upload. Which are 128KB and 16KB.

When you want to release the caps.

```
$ sudo wondershaper clear eth1
```

These are pretty capable tools so this is just meant to show you the potential.

#### References

- [How do I limit internet bandwidth?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20872/how-do-i-limit-internet-bandwidth)
- [Control your bandwidth with Trickle](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/control-your-bandwidth-trickle)